# The proportionality of a Drag force and speed

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, aerodynamics, speed, turbulence

At low speeds, Drag force is proportional to speed due to Stokes law.
At higher speeds, Drag is proportional to the square of speed.

While modelling the speed of a water rocket, I realised that when there was inherently high drag in the system - say the coefficient of drag is 1.00 - the model fit very well when I placed drag force proportional to v^2. However, when there was inherently lower drag in the system - say the coefficient of drag is 0.5 - the model doesn't fit well for $v^2$. Instead, interestingly enough, it fits very well for values such as $v^{2.8}$ or $v^3$.

Now, is it reasonable to argue that the reason this happens is because of the following:
When there is inherently higher drag, the rocket attains lower speeds, and hence is proportional to lower powers of velocity. Similarly, when there  is inherently lower  drag, the system attains higher speeds and therefore is proportional to higher powers of velocity.

I know the argument is a bit of a loop, but I just can't believe how perfectly $v^{2.8}$ fits the model with low drag while v^2 fits the model with high drag.
Additionally, a major problem with raising velocity to higher/non integer powers is that the units do not match to give Newtons.
So, is this argument reasonable? If yes how would I make the units consistent?

Comment: In terms of dimensionless groups, the units can always be made consistent.  The probable reason that the exponent is different than you expected is that there was air flow, not only along the length of the rocket,, but also perpendicular to the axis; and this non-linear interaction fed back into the axial drag.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the drag coefficient is 0.5, 1.0,or any particular value. If it is constant, then the drag force will be proportional to v**2. If it varies (which it almost always does to some extent), then it's not surprising that some other exponent might give a better fit.

Comment: How would I make the units consistent?  Actually I tried modelling by comparing my graphs with those given by a simulator(hopefully its right). I presume that it neglects any affects of horizontal wind as there is no space to input it, or any changes in coefficient of drag because there is only one space to input it. Of course, there is still a decent probability that the simulator is wrong. But still how would I fix the issue with the units?